Using CSS variable as property value in React
Is the below way of passing CSS variable as property value an official/standard way that React works? I haven't seen this documented in React, but it works, in the sense, that when the variable value changes it changes within the ColoredBox component, too. While it works now, I don't know if it is future proof.
<ColoredBox test="var(--main-bg-color)" />

inside ColoredBox
function ColoredBox({color}) {
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: color}}>I'm a colored box</div>
}

App.js
import "./styles.css"

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ColoredBox color="var(--main-bg-color)"/>
        </div>
    )
}

styles.css
.App {
    --main-bg-color: blue;
}

.App.brown {
    --main-bg-color: brown;
}

Once the app is rendered, when I add the class "brown" to App div, it changes the color.

So why it should not work?

yes.. I did a few experiments and figured like I was wrongly interpreting the role of React in this kind of scenario. Understood that React treats "var(--main-bg-color)" as just any other string and doesn't do any magic here. It is just that the context in which this string is used (e.g. in markup or CSS) CSS variables are supported. However, I also figured, in some context like Canvas it will not work. Although, React has nothing to do with that. Anyhow, you are right. There is no reason for this to not work in applicable contexts.
